# Notepad++ renders some utf8 characters only when another utf8 characters are present

Tags: encoding, utf-8, notepad++

I noticed when I try to write characters such as `∃` `∈` `⟧` (resp. U+2203 U+2208 U+27E7) and so on don't render, i.e. show as empty squares. When I write the symbol `∀` (U+2200), they all render.

There are some simple conditions that I noticed while playing - if they are separated (from `∀`) by a tabulation or a new line (windows, i.e. CR LF).

I tried all the encodings (ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-8 BOM, UTF-16 BE BOM, UTF-16 LE BOM) and all the "View -> Show Symbol" options available to my Notepad++ version.

Version: Notepad++ v8.6 (64-bit)
OS: Windows 11 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2715) - I assume irrelevant, but for completeness.

Comment: All those empty squares are [Glyph 0: the `.notdef` glyph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph). Instead of playing with different encodings (keep [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) if possible), check used font (*Settings* -> *Style configurator*).

Comment: Thank you, changing the font worked out!
P.S. I went through them all and almost none work, but "Cambria" works just fine!